# What is "Dim" Used for in ASP?

Tags: asp-classic, vbscript

I've been googling around and had not that much success in getting an understanding of what "Dim" is used for in ASP (I'm obviously very new to ASP, so apologies for my dim-wittedness..).

I see dim used as though it is for 'declaring' variables or something of that nature?  Can someone please clarify its purpose/use/functionality?  Thanks!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes, 'Dim' (short for dimension) declares a variable in VBScript:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zexdsyc0(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: I can assume this will be the same for ASP, functionally speaking?  Just creates a generic variable with no specific type (as typical)?  The code I was looking was strictly ASP without any scripting in it, unless im misunderstanding how scripting works in ASP.

Comment: Classic ASP pages are normally written in VBScript (although other languages can be used, see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Active_Server_Pages).